# Emulate php openssl_decrypt function in Java with hardcoded key

Tags: java, php, encryption

I need to replicate functionality in java, **NOT IMPROVE** PHP code.

Php 7 code:

```
openssl_encrypt("123::secret", "aes-256-cbc", "1234567899999999", 0, "0123456789999999");
// VZq5nLyJaAzajWQqMMLgmQ==

openssl_decrypt("VZq5nLyJaAzajWQqMMLgmQ==", "aes-256-cbc", "1234567899999999", 0, "0123456789999999");
// 123::secret
```

In Java, I want to make the same, so PHP would be able to decrypt it

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("1234567899999999".getBytes(), "AES"), new IvParameterSpec("0123456789999999".getBytes()));
byte[] res = cipher.doFinal("123::secret".getBytes());
java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(res);

// xIwXN6R+X/FMMqfmsYhEQQ==
```

But, this key is different and PHP returns false on decrypt attempt. I find many solutions, but they around generating random 256 key lengths, but in my situation PHP code is using hardcoded secret

Comment: You specify `aes-256-cbc` in the PHP code, but _inconsistently_ use a 16 bytes key. PHP expands keys that are too short by extending the key with `0x00` values to the required size. The Java code does not do this automatically, here the key expansion must be done explicitly to make the results match. The better fix is of course to use a 32 bytes key.

Comment: Btw, key and IV are insecure, hopefully it's just test data. Also you should specify the encoding in the Java code (e.g. `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`).

Comment: Can you please suggest, how can I make data key expansion to be on same page with php?

Comment: A 16 bytes key is invalid for AES-256. Why don't you use a 32 bytes key? Or the other way around, if you have a 16 bytes key, why don't you apply AES-128?

Comment: If neither key nor algorithm may be changed in the PHP code, use `"1234567899999999\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` as key in the Java code to generate the ciphertext of the _current_ PHP code.

Comment: you save me! yes, multiplay  `\0` was the key.

Answer (score 1):

Topaca's answer is correct (php code can not be changed). To fully emulate described PHP function with provided arguments, need to update the password with "\0" to meet the length requirement